# Stop ng-model on updating ng-disabled input from an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with 5 days of the week which is an `ng-repeat` for each day and I have a button somewhere on the page who populates all inputs with some data coming from the backend.

This is my code:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Days</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
<td ng-repeat="day in days">
  <input type="text" ng-model="day.start" ng-disabled="item.date > currentDate"
</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And I have a button with an `ng-click="someFunction()"` which is a `REST API` method `GET` and from backend it will populate my repeater.

The problem is in the current week page when let's say it's wednesday, thursday and friday are disabled but when I click my button it will populate all my 5 `inputs` from `ng-repeat` with data and I only want to populate monday, tuesday and wednesday if the rest of the days are disabled by `ng-disabled`.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-if and check whether the day is available or not

```
<input type="text" ng-model="day.start" ng-if="item.date > currentDate"
```

if the condition is valid then only dom element will appear on the page

Comment: I've thought on that solution but it won't help me because I want to display all 5 inputs but I want ng-model to populate only those who are not disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide getters and setters to input via ng-model-options, and use noop setter for disabled inputs.

Comment: Can you provide more details please? I've looked on the web for ng-model-options and setter methods but I didn't manage to make something out of it. I've never used ng-model-options.